# How to undo a merge that happened several commits ago, while preserving those later commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I'm working an a PHP project on an 8 person team with git.  For the past week, I've been working on my git branch, making several commits per day.  I am also merging our production branch into my local branch every few days to keep merge conflicts under control.

Today, I realized that I made a mistake a few days (and many commits) ago Instead of merging production into my brach, I accidentally merged in a developmental branch (that contained a new feature that several other people were working on.) My branch now contains lots of code that is not ready to go to production!  I need to remove/revert this merge, but preserve all of the changes that I made after that merge was completed.

I want to keep everything in my original branch, because that branch has already been pushed to gitlab, and has accumulated lots of comments and revision requests.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I accidentally merged in a developmental branch

If you have not yet pushed that `dev` branch, you can

- cherry-pick the commits you have made in dev since the merge to the right branch
- reset dev before that merge.